# Expectations of mean squared error

Tags: statistics, expected-value, mean-square-error

I am currently studying the expected mean squared error and the derivations of this are as follows:

\begin{align}
&E[(y_i - \hat{y}_0 | x_0]\\
&=E [ (f(x) + \epsilon_i - \hat{f}(x_i))^2 | x_0]\\
&=E [(f(x) - \hat{f}(x_i))^2|x_0] + 2 E [(f(x_i)-\hat{f}(x_i))\epsilon_i | x_0] + E[\epsilon_0^2 |x_0]\\
\end{align}

From which we can further get the bias and variance. But I do not understand the following, what rule is used in order to rewrite it using the following part: $2 E [(f(x_i)-\hat{f}(x_i))\epsilon_i | x_0]$ ?

Comment: $(a+b)^2 = a^2 +2ab + b^2$.

Comment: Wow, it was extremely easy, thanks a lot! I was not able to see it haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s important to note that the expected value operator $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]$ is a linear operator. Therefore, it holds with two random variables $X, Y$ and constant scalar $\lambda$:

1. $\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[Y]$, and
2. $\mathbb{E}[\lambda X] = \lambda \mathbb{E}[X]$.

So you only need to apply binomial expansion to obtain:
$$\mathbb{E}[((f(x) - \hat{f}(x_i)) + \epsilon_i)^2] =\\
\mathbb{E}[(f(x) - \hat{f}(x_i))^2 + 2 (f(x_i)-\hat{f}(x_i))\ \epsilon_i + \epsilon_i^2] =\\
\mathbb{E}[(f(x) - \hat{f}(x_i))^2] + 2 \mathbb{E}[(f(x_i)-\hat{f}(x_i))\ \epsilon_i] + \mathbb{E}[\epsilon_i^2]$$.